# Call each function in a literal object (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, iteration

How can I call each function in this object?

```
var obj = {
  hey1: function() {
    alert('hey');
  },
  hey2: function() {
    alert('hey2');
  },
  hey3: function() {
    alert('hey3');
  }
}
```

I'd like each function to run one after the other. I'm looking for something like:

```
for (var hey in obj) {
  hey();
}
```

But obviously that doesn't run (otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question).

Thanks guys!!!

Comment: If only javascript reflection..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (var hey in obj) {
    obj[hey]();
}
```

In a situation where it is not guaranteed that each property will be a function, you can weed out other properties:

```
for (var hey in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[hey] == "function") {
        obj[hey]();
    }
}
```

To further restrict it to only immediate properties of the object (and not the ones inherited from its prototype):

```
for (var hey in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[hey] == "function" && obj.hasOwnProperty(hey)) {
        obj[hey]();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lopping will give you they keys, not the values. Use the key to get the value:

```
for (var hey in obj) {
  obj[hey]();
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/s8tbr/](http://jsfiddle.net/s8tbr/)

Note: Depending on from where you get the object, you might want to check that the properties are members of the object itself, not inherited from a prototype:

```
for (var hey in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(hey)) {
    obj[hey]();
  }
}
```